# Curly Brackets broken

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using UnityEngine;

public class GunScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float damage = 10f;
    public float fireRate = 1f;
    public float range = 100f;

    private float nextTimeToFire = 0f;

    public Camera MainCam;
    public ParticleSystem muzzleFlash;
    public GameObject impactEffect;
    public GameObject bulletDecal;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && Time.time >= nextTimeToFire)
        {
            nextTimeToFire = Time.time + 1f / fireRate;
            Shoot();
        }
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        muzzleFlash.Play();
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(MainCam.transform.position, MainCam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
        {
            Target target = hit.transform.GetComponent<Target>();

            if (target != null)
            {
                target.TakeDamage(damage);
            }

            GameObject ImpactGO = Instantiate(impactEffect, hit.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal));
            GameObject bulletDecalGO = Instantiate(bulletDecal);

            Vector3 zFighting = new Vector3(-0.001f, 0f, -0.001f);
            Vector3 zFighting2 = new Vector3(0.001f, 0f, 0.001f);

            if (hit.normal == new Vector3(0f, 0f, -1.0f) || hit.normal == new Vector3(-1.0f, 0f, 0f)
            {
                bulletDecalGO.transform.position = zFighting + hit.point;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The order of them are broken I am a beginner please help. I don't know what happened please help. I am writing these because it says my post is mostly code. help pls thx.

Comment: you're missing a closing bracket in the line `if (hit.normal ...`

Comment: When you place the cursor over an opening curly, bracket oe paranthesis the closing one will be highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing paren at the end here:

```
if (hit.normal == new Vector3(0f, 0f, -1.0f) || hit.normal == new Vector3(-1.0f, 0f, 0f)
```

should be

```
if (hit.normal == new Vector3(0f, 0f, -1.0f) || hit.normal == new Vector3(-1.0f, 0f, 0f))
```

With that: it should fix itself.

(as a side note: comparing floating points exactly may be inadvisable)

Comment: Thank you so much! I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your refactored code. But I would suggest you to try it by yourself. First start with opening and closing brackets. you can also do ctrl k + d if you are using the VS, so that you can see the formatted code, it will be easy for you to debug the issue.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using UnityEngine;

public class GunScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float damage = 10f;
    public float fireRate = 1f;
    public float range = 100f;

    private float nextTimeToFire = 0f;

    public Camera MainCam;
    public ParticleSystem muzzleFlash;
    public GameObject impactEffect;
    public GameObject bulletDecal;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && Time.time >= nextTimeToFire)
        {
            nextTimeToFire = Time.time + 1f / fireRate;
            Shoot();
        }
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        muzzleFlash.Play();
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(MainCam.transform.position, MainCam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
        {
            Target target = hit.transform.GetComponent<Target>();

            if (target != null)
            {
                target.TakeDamage(damage);
            }

            GameObject ImpactGO = Instantiate(impactEffect, hit.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal));
            GameObject bulletDecalGO = Instantiate(bulletDecal);

            Vector3 zFighting = new Vector3(-0.001f, 0f, -0.001f);
            Vector3 zFighting2 = new Vector3(0.001f, 0f, 0.001f);

            if (hit.normal == new Vector3(0f, 0f, -1.0f) || hit.normal == new Vector3(-1.0f, 0f, 0f))
            {
                bulletDecalGO.transform.position = zFighting + hit.point;
            }
        }
    }
}
```